# Does "..." have meaning as a relative pathname? (EDIT: No.)

Tags: windows, filesystems

#### 1. Is there a relative pathname/directory/folder meaning for the expression "..."?
 2. What does "..." refer to in the context cited?

I encountered the expression "..." when looking at the installation instructions for http://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/wiki/Win64Binaries and it says the following (note bolded text):

> Unzip the zipfile into a directory whose name ends in vim, such as C:\Program Files\Vim, D:\vim, or C:\mytools\vim. This will create a vim72 subdirectory, containing all the files. 
>   `Start a cmd.exe window, cd ...\vim\vim72`, then run install.exe, the command-line installer. This will offer you a series of choices. You can probably just type d to "do it".`

---

*Bonus points for listing all relative directory pathnames!*

Comment: No - it's just shorthand for "whatever", i.e. whatever your path happens to be to this particular subdirectory.

Comment: As far as I know . and .. are the only ones. The triple dot probably is shorthand for 'wherever vim is installed'.

Comment: Old timer trivia: on Win9x systems (but not NT-based systems), the `cd` command would treat `...` similarly to `..\..` and `....` similarly to `..\..\..` and so on.  at least for the `cd` command (I don't think it worked like that in general).  I wish this carried over to NT - it was a handy shortcut.

Comment: Why is this downvoted when it's a feasible syntax question about a popular programming-related topic?

Comment: I'm confused about this because `...` and other numbers of dots beyond 3 are interpreted as an existing directory name with no contents. If you `dir ...` it has no contents. If you `cd ...` you end up in the same place. If you `rd ...` it says it is in use by another process. One might think it's the same as `.` but if you `rd /s .` it will erase the contents of the current directory before saying that it is in use. If you `rd /s ...` it will not erase anything but just say it is in use.

Comment: If you `cd .\..` you go up one level but if you `cd ...\..` you go nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `...` in this case means anything like "up one/two/three levels". I have never heard of `...` having a meaning for the `cd` command for example.

I think they're referring to the fact that they don't know where you actually unzipped the archive, so `...\vim\vim72` could mean `C:\Program Files\vim\vim72` or `D:\vim` or `C:\mytools\vim\vim72` etc.

Comment: I agree! That was my first impression-- "..." typically denotes silence or maybe, more abstractly, emptiness.

Answer (score 2):

There is no formal meaning, but a common interpretation is *"the path leading up
to that point"*, since the ellipsis generally indicates silence or a pause or void or gap.